# Deploying react to the web

Tags: reactjs

with this message
" 'meta[name=theme-color]' is not supported by Firefox, Firefox for Android, Internet Explorer, Opera, Safari < 15, Safari on iOS < 15." how can i fix the the problem of deploying my mern app in the web

Answer (score 0):

Here is table of supporting this meta tag. https://caniuse.com/#feat=meta-theme-color